# How to do the code in Slide Puzzle. On JAVA

Tags: java, slide, sliding-tile-puzzle

*First my English is not good please try to understand me.
I want to create the Slide Puzzle game but I didn't understand about method to slide a block and method Click for slide event.(I mean MouseLister)
Now I have only GUI

```
public PGWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SlidePuzzle");
    JPanel Board = new JPanel();
    Board.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    Font fn = new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 60);
    int Num = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            if (Num == 9) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                Board.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(+Num))).setFont(fn);
            }
            Num++;
        }
    }

    frame.add(Board);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setLocation(600, 90);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Java GUI, but hope these hints help you to achieve what you want.

Imagine that someone click on block 8. A click event will be triggered, and it should call the method that slides the block effectively.

You have to build some method `slideBlock(int blockId)` that checks if the block can be moved or not, and also have defined somewhere a matrix that holds the game state.

It should start ordered and you have to define some method that shuffles the puzzle correclty, in order to exist a way to user reorder the puzzle. Let's see some pseudo-code:

```
//The matrix initial state:
int[][] grid = new int[gridLength][gridLength];
int piece = 1;

//Fill the grid with the puzzle ordered:
for(0<=row<gridLength) {
        for(0<=col<gridLength) {
            if(row != gridLength - 1 && col != gridLength - 1) { //Leave last block empty
                grid[row][col] = piece
                piece++
            }
        }
 }

public void shuffle() {
        //Some shuffle that makes sense
 }

public void slideBlock(int blockId) {
        //Get the indexes where the block is, e.g. getPositions() and hold them on some vars, e.g. row, col
        boolean moved = false;

        if(row - 1 > 0 && grid[row - 1][col] == 0){  // Move block up
            grid[row - 1][col] = blockId
            moved = true;
        }
        else if(row + 1 < gridLength - 1 && grid[row + 1][col] == 0) { // Move block down
            grid[row + 1][col] = blockId
            moved = true;
        }
        else if(col - 1 > 0 && grid[row][col - 1] == 0) {  // Move block left
            grid[row][col - 1] = blockId
            moved = true;
        }
        else if(col + 1 < gridLength - 1 && grid[row][col + 1] == 0) { // Move block right
            grid[row][col + 1] = blockId
            moved = true;
        }

        if moved
            grid[row][col] = 0 // Delete the piece from old position
 }
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It means that your variable `row` will go from `0` to `gridLength - 1`, i.e. `for(int row = 0; row < gridLength - 1; row++)`